# how to find the number of response object in json

Tags: json, rest-assured

I have a JSON response to validate. I am writing a test secario where I want to assert if the response contains the number of objects or not. JSON response:

```json
{
  "Result": {
    "resultCode": "1000",
  },
  "ResultClient": {
    "responseCode": null,
    "statusCode": null
  },
  "creditCard": {
    "number": null
  }
}
```

I want to assert that the response has 3 objects. How to do that? The response obj dosn't have `size()` or `count()` so I am unable to understand the path to the solution.I am writting my tests in rest-assured .

```
TestResponse testResponse = given()
                .contentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .body(cTestRequest)
                .when()
                .post(uri)
                .as(TestResponse.class);
```

now how to assert the json contains the 3 obj and the parameters inside the objs?

Comment: Please include the test code you're stuck on directly in your question by editing it.

Comment: I added the assertion by asserting that the 3 expected objects are not null.

Comment: Yes, that's sounds relevant - add the code you're talking about to the question. Adding the error message and/or stack trace will increase chances of you getting help, too *(currently they're not much greater than 0%)*.

Comment: What language is this? In JS this would be `Object.keys(result).length === 3`.

Comment: modified the question by adding more data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
when().
       get("/x").
then().
       body("keySet().size()", is(3));
```

The reason is that the JSON object is treated as Groovy `Map` so you can invoke functions on it. `keySet()` returns all keys as a `Set` and `size()` returns the size of this `Set`.